# Does noexcept matter with explicitly defaulted move constructor/assignment operator?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, noexcept

```
class C
{
    public:
        C(C&&) = default; // (1)
        C& operator=(C&&) = default; // (1)

        C(C&&) noexcept = default; // (2)
        C& operator=(C&&) noexcept = default; // (2)
}
```

As far as I know, if move constructor/assignment operator are either implicitly generated or explicitly defaulted by user `(1)`, the compiler will decide whether these special member functions should be `noexcept` or not depending on whether all the members of a class provide `noexcept` guarantees for move operations. But what if I want to use default move special members and force them to be `noexcept` regardless of the underlying members exception guarantees for move operations? Is there any difference for the compiler between `(1)` and `(2)` declarations?

Comment: Yes it matters... moving with noexcept can be optimized by the compiler (specialy true when moving in containers like in std::sort)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer in Nico's Josuttis book "C++ Move Semantics - The Complete Guide":

> When you have a defaulted special member function you can explicitly
> specify a different noexcept guarantee than the generated one. For
> example:
>
> ```
> class C
> {
>   ...
>  public:
>   C(const C&) noexcept = default;     // guarantees not to throw (OK since C++20)
>   C(C&&) noexcept(false) = default;   // specifies that it might throw (OK since C++20)
>   ...
> };
> ```
>
> Before C++20, if the generated and specified noexcept condition
> contradict, the defined function was deleted.

I asked this question because I want STL algorithms to always apply move semantics to my classes regardless of their members' exception guarantees, and I am ready to deal with `std::abort` if something goes wrong. But it seems that prior to C++ 20 the only way to force `noexcept` guarantees on move special member functions was to explicitly define them, even if you don't need your own implementation. It turns out C++20 solved this by allowing us to specify `noexcept` guarantees for defaulted special member functions. Of course, as in case with any other `noexcept` function, if any of the members of a class throws during a move operation, `std::abort` will be called if move constructor/assignment operator are declared `noexcept` for that class, as it was kindly pointed out by **@MichaëlRoy** in the comments section.

Comment: @Alexey104.   This means that for a move constructor,  the default noexcept condition is equal to `noexcept(noexcept(X::X(X&&)...);` where `X...` are the types of the members of your class.  So, if you specify noexcept, and one of you data members' constructor throws, your program will perform a hard exit.  This definitely is worth mentioning in your answer, since before c++20, this kind of behavior was not possible.

Comment: I meant `noexcept(noexcept(X::X(X&&) && ...)` sorry for the typo.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy >`"So, if you specify noexcept, and one of you data members' constructor throws, your program will perform a hard exit."` Yes, I understand that, and I intentionally want this behavior. I want STL algorithms to always apply move semantics to my classes regardless of of their members' exception guarantees, and I accept `std::abort` if something goes wrong. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Perhaps mention this behavior in the answer for others reading this Q&A.

Comment: @Alexey104  Cool.  I pointed it out because I also think it's worth mentioning in your answer.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, oh, I missed your last sentence, sorry.

Comment: If your constructor is noexcept(true), then any exception in any data member constructor will cause an abort,regardless of that particular constructor noexcept status.

Comment: Sure, that is exactly what I meant. Sometimes I just struggle to formulate the right sentence due to my bad English, but I am working on this.